# Date formatting for bar charts in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to plot data against specific dates on the x-axis using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486121/how-to-plot-data-against-specific-dates-on-the-x-axis-using-matplotlib)
>   [Plot with non-numerical data on x axis (for ex., dates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974847/plot-with-non-numerical-data-on-x-axis-for-ex-dates)

I am attempting to generate a bar graph in matplotlib where the x-axis and y-axis values are tuples of (dates, integers). The data has the following form:

```
data = [('2012-02-26', 17), ('2012-03-07', 16), ('2012-06-30', 16), 
        ('2012-03-16', 15), ('2012-06-24', 15), ('2012-05-13', 14), 
        ('2012-03-19', 12), ('2012-02-18', 9), ('2012-04-07', 9), 
        ('2012-04-09', 8)]
```

I can generate a simple bar graph if I simply use integers as x values:

```
import scipy as sp
from matplotlib import pyplot as pl
x = sp.arange(100)
y = sp.random.randint(1,100, 100)
fig = figure()
pl.bar(x,y)
```

[image]

How can I plot a similar bar graph with string dates on the x-axis? Ideally, I would also like to have the x-axis labels show as dates. I found a similar example on the [matplotlib recipe page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/recipes.html), but I could not get it to work with my example. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the plot_date function instead of plot().

[plot_date](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date)

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m'))
```