# Plotting Dates from Numpy Array Problems

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm plotting a CSV file of weather data, and I got it to import just fine in my code, but i'm trying to plot it. Here's a sample of the CSV data:

```
12:00am,171,6,7,52,76,77.1,63.7,28.74,0.00,0.00,0.0,0,63.7,78.1,67.4,56.0,29.96
12:01am,192,4,6,52,76,77.1,63.7,28.74,0.00,0.00,0.0,0,63.7,78.1,67.4,56.0,29.96
12:02am,197,3,6,52,76,77.1,63.7,28.74,0.00,0.00,0.0,0,63.7,78.1,67.4,56.0,29.96
12:03am,175,3,6,52,76,77.1,63.7,28.73,0.00,0.00,0.0,0,63.7,78.1,67.4,56.0,29.96
12:04am,194,4,6,52,76,77.1,63.7,28.73,0.00,0.00,0.0,0,63.7,78.1,67.4,56.0,29.96
12:05am,148,5,6,52,76,77.1,63.7,28.73,0.00,0.00,0.0,0,63.7,78.1,67.4,56.0,29.96
```

Anyway, I'd like the time to be on the X axis, but I can't get it to plot using matplotlib. I tried a method using xticks, and it plotted my y values, but that was it. It just gave me a thick solid line on my X axis.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import datetime as DT
import re

data = np.genfromtxt('FILE.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, skip_header=3)
length = len(data)

x = data['f0']
y = data['f7']

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("Temperature")    
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Degrees')


#plt.plot_date(x, y)
plt.show()
leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

I'm missing a few crucial parts because I honestly don't know where to go from here. I checked the data type of my numpy array, and it kept saying numpy.ndarray, and I can't find a way to convert it to a string or an int value to plot. It's a 24 hour CSV file, and I would like tick marks every 30 minutes or so. Any ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574088/plotting-time-in-python-with-matplotlib) is possible related.

Comment: Tried that, but I got a bunch of errors and it never plotted or output data. I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974847/plot-with-non-numerical-data-on-x-axis-for-ex-dates and I got just a solid black line on the x axis, probably because there is a good 600 tick marks. How would I change that?

Comment: I've had success with giving plt.plot() a list of datetime objects for the x coordinates and then a list of floats for the y values. I'm not sure what a convenient way to get that out of a numpy array would be, or how to really control the tick marks, but that might at least give you a chart.

Comment: pandas is pretty good at importing csv data,  Parsing good and has some basic plotting functionality.  After examining data can go back to pure matplotlib functionality.

Comment: I've posted an answer.  I tested it, and it works on my computer (always gotta have that disclaimer).

Comment: If my answer or @bmu's answer worked for you, please select one as the accepted answer.  Otherwise, let me know how my answer _didn't_ work and I'll be glad to help.  If you went with your own solution, please post it here and accept it.  Note also that I changed my answer to work with Python 2.7 and all times.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not very elegant, but it works.  The key is to **change the times stored in `x`, which are just strings, to datetime objects** so that matploblib can plot them.  I have made a function that does the conversion and called it `get_datetime_from_string`.

** Edited code to be compatible with Python 2.7 and work with times with single digit hours **

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import datetime as DT
import re

def get_datetime_from_string(time_string):
    ''' Returns a datetime.datetime object

        Args
        time_string: a string of the form 'xx:xxam'
        '''

    # there's got to be a better way to do this.
    # Convert it to utf-8 so string slicing works as expected.
    time_string = unicode(time_string, 'utf-8')

    # period is either am or pm
    colon_position = time_string.find(':')
    period = time_string[-2:]
    hour = int(time_string[:colon_position])
    if period.lower() == 'pm':
        hour += 12

    minute = int(time_string[colon_position + 1:colon_position + 3])

    return DT.datetime(1,1,1,hour, minute)

data = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None, skip_header=3)
length=len(data)

x=data['f0']
y=data['f7']

datetimes = [get_datetime_from_string(t) for t in x]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Temperature")    
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Degrees')

plt.plot(datetimes, y)
leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

I kept getting tripped up because I was trying to do string slicing on `time_string` before converting it to `utf-8`.  Before it was giving me the ASCII values or something.  I'm not sure why converting it helped, but it did.

Comment: When I add that to my code, I get the error:File "metogram.py", line 22, in get_datetime_from_string
    hour = int(time_string[:2])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1:'

Comment: Realized I made a small mistake in adapting that to mine, and now the new error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "metogram.py", line 36, in <module>
    datetimes = [get_datetime_from_string(t) for t in x]
  File "metogram.py", line 20, in get_datetime_from_string
    time_string = str(time_string, 'utf-8')
TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Try it without the conversion. In other words, try it without the line `time_string = str(time_string, 'utf-8')`.

Comment: By the way, the reason that breaks for you and not for me is that I'm using Python version 3.3, and you're not :-).

Comment: I got Cody Piersall's code to work by changeing "time_string = str(time_string, 'utf-8')" to "time_string = unicode(time_string, 'utf-8')" and "plt.plot_date(datetimes, y)" to "plt.plot(datetimes, y)". I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Your code works with the snippet of csv I provided, but not with the whole CSV since it breaks when it gets to times like 1:30am with one number in the hour column.

Comment: I changed the function to work with both types of times by checking for the position of the colon--note the addition of the `colon_position` variable in the `get_datetime_from_string` function.  It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is a very useful library for time series analysis and has some plotting features based on matplotlib.

Pandas uses `dateutil` internally to parse dates, however the problem is, that the date isn't included in your file. In the code below I assume, that you will know the date before parsing the file (from the file name?)

```
In [125]: import pandas as pd
In [126]: pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
In [127]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [128]: class DateParser():                                          
   .....:     def __init__(self, datestring):
   .....:         self.datestring = datestring
   .....:     def get_datetime(self, time):    
   .....:         return dateutil.parser.parse(' '.join([self.datestring, time]))
   .....:     

In [129]: dp = DateParser('2013-01-01')

In [130]: df = pd.read_csv('weather_data.csv', sep=',', index_col=0, header=None,
                  parse_dates={'datetime':[0]}, date_parser=dp.get_datetime)

In [131]: df.ix[:, :12] # show the first columns
Out[131]: 
                      1   2   3   4   5     6     7      8   9   10  11  12  
datetime                                                                      
2013-01-01 00:00:00  171   6   7  52  76  77.1  63.7  28.74   0   0   0   0   
2013-01-01 00:01:00  192   4   6  52  76  77.1  63.7  28.74   0   0   0   0   
2013-01-01 00:02:00  197   3   6  52  76  77.1  63.7  28.74   0   0   0   0   
2013-01-01 00:03:00  175   3   6  52  76  77.1  63.7  28.73   0   0   0   0   
2013-01-01 00:04:00  194   4   6  52  76  77.1  63.7  28.73   0   0   0   0   
2013-01-01 00:05:00  148   5   6  52  76  77.1  63.7  28.73   0   0   0   0   

In [132]: ax = df.ix[:,1:3].plot(secondary_y=1)

In [133]: ax.margins(0.04)

In [134]: plt.tight_layout()

In [135]: plt.savefig('weather_data.png')
```

[image: weather_data.png]